# Injecting a src into HTML5's audio tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I'm trying to use HTML5's audio controls and inject a dynamic path into the audio source, using JavaScript/jQuery.

Here's my markup:

```
<audio id="marker" controls>
<source src="placeholder.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

and here's my attempt to overwrite the placeholder source:

```
var audio = $('#marker');
audio.src(path.mp3);
```

My expected result is that I can use the audio controls to play the audio located at `path.mp3`, but instead the audio controls are greyed out, and it plays nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: jQuery object doesn't have `src` method. Why are you trying to use a method that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With js

```
var audio = document.getElementById("marker")
audio.src = "path.mp3"
```

And this would be with jQuery

```
var audio = $("#marker")
$(audio).attr("src","path.mp3")
```

If you want to get the native DOM element from the jQuery object

```
var audio = $("#marker")[0]
```

And then you can access it's src attribute

```
audio.src = "path.mp3"
```